# SHAREPOINT FRAMEWORK - REACT JS alert on Page Load

Tags: spfx-webparts, alert, dropdown, sharepoint-framework, reactjs

I am new to SharePoint framework and React JS.

I have build a basic Web Part with CRUD operation using React JS.

I wanted to show drop-down(html select) value on Page Load in an alert. I am able to get an alert on page load but not able to figure out how to get html select value in that alert.

Please advice.

Here is my code for getting alert on page load.

```
componentDidMount() {   
  alert("Hi");
}



public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactCrudProps> {   
    return ( 
        <select id="myDDl">

        </select>
    );
}
```

Comment: Which drop-down value? Do you have any drop-down in your web part? If Yes, please add HTML code.

Comment: edited my question to add the render method with dropdown(select html) code

Comment: Have you mapped the select options from state or stored selected value in state? See [this](https://www.carlrippon.com/react-drop-down-data-binding/), it might help you.

Comment: you cannot display custom html in alert...alert is javascript method...to display dropdown in popup, use some either jquery/bootstrap or react popup...

Comment: He/she want to show the drop-down(html select) **value**. not drop-down. If he/she can get the drop-down value in `componentDidMount` function maybe using React state or some javascript then he/she can show it in an alert.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to do it:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './Reactspfx.module.scss';
import { IReactspfxProps } from './IReactspfxProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
 export interface IReactGetItemsState{ 
selectValue:string
}
export default class Reactspfx extends React.Component<IReactspfxProps, 
  IReactGetItemsState> {
public constructor(props: IReactspfxProps) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  selectValue:"Radish"
};

}

 handleChange = (event) => {
this.setState({selectValue:event.target.value});
alert(event.target.value);
};

 public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactspfxProps> {
alert(this.state.selectValue);
return (
  
  <select value={this.state.selectValue}  onChange={this.handleChange}>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
      <option value="Radish">Radish</option>
      <option value="Cherry">Cherry</option>
    </select>
);
}
```